# Allow Sites guest to edit contact

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites

I have a sites visualforce page. I can input my employee number and return with name and email(apex:input so i can edit). but as a guest in the salesforce site, I only have read and create access. how can i update the email in contacts through this salesforce sites? thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the Sites you can't update Standard object records.

As per your requirement create one custom object. In that object create fields which fields you want to update in contact

In this custom object create trigger to update in Contact!!

Comment: I am calling the email field for contact in apex:inputtext so when guest updated it, it will update the email in contact.

Comment: yes create email field in Custom object then write a trigger in custom object to copy the values from custom object to Contact.

Comment: but the filed value of apexinput is from contact. If the user edit that field it will go to email field in contact also @mani

Comment: In apexinput you need to add custom object email field not the contact field.. In trigger you can map this field with your contact field!!